# How do I load entire file content as a text into a column AzureSQLDW table?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a some file in an azure data lake 2 and I want to load them as a column value nvarchar(max) in AzureSQLDW. The table in AzureSQLDW is heap. I couldn't find any way to do it? All I see is column delimited when load them into multiple rows instead of one row in single column. How I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text) confirms that the "No delimiter" (aka "empty string") option for row and for column delimiters is "only supported for mapping data flow but not Copy activity."
[Microsoft wording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFbkC.png)

The only workaround I can find for this when using Copy Activity is same as you, setting the delimiter to a non-printable character not present in file, which will work same as no delimiter unless that character at some point appears in a file.

Note that setting empty string to parameter for dataset also doesn't work in Copy Activity
[parameratise also doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt8A3.png)

Vote for the feature in the Azure ideas forum if interested [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/1c4084cb-9dbc-ed11-a81b-6045bd79fc6e)

Answer (score 0):

I don't guarantee this will work, but try using COPY INTO and define non-present values for row and column delimiters. Make your target a single column table.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Source Dataset with a single column. You do this by specifying "No delimiter":

[image]

Next, go to the "Schema" tab and Import the schema, which should create a single column called "Prop_0":
[image]

Now the data should come through as a single string instead of delimited columns.

Comment: Thank you but when I use that dataset into copy activity I am getting following error message
Column delimiter cannot be empty string or multi-character string when dataset is referenced in Copy data1.

Comment: I finally solved this issue by selecting Row Delimiter as ~ character. I had to make sure that that character is not present in the file and Column Delimiter as | and I had to make sure same thing.

However, I could load up to only 198124 characters. Not sure why? My destination have only one column and it is of type varchar(max) with heap structure.

Comment: Indicating a non-existent delimiter is basically the same thing as No delimiter, but it will break or cause problems if your data ever includes that character. I think using No delimiter is more accurate and descriptive of your intent, but glad you got it working.

Comment: I missed your first comment about Copy activity - that doesn't surprise me. It didn't occur to me because I focus on Data Flows these days instead of Copy.